# Vectorize on array of bool in c++

Tags: c++, vectorization

I have an array of bool (or any equivalent structure). I need to count the number of true between the nth and mth position. Is it possible to get the compiler to vectorize this so that 64 or more elements are checked in one go?

Comment: In fact, the way it is at the moment, it is an array of char that can be '0' or '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That already happens if you compile with `-O3` and potentially `-march=native`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void count(char* v) {
    auto x = std::count(&v[0], &v[100], true);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

With gcc, this gives you a bunch of vp* instructions, which means that the count is vectorized. You can easily check this on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GPbhEeK3b).

Comment: Is there a way to use bool instead of char to get 8 times as many operations? Thank you

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` does not seem to be parallelized, likely because of its proxy iterators. I'd look into bitpacking libraries and/or use simd popcount: https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a speciation of `std::vector` for `bool`: [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) but it's not great and doesn't have a count function.

Instead you could consider using [`std:: bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), that does offer a [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count) member function. It's more or less designed for the purpose and will likely have an efficient implementation.